Is it true that only prosecutors can 'cut a deal' with criminals?
It's a common trope on US cop/law shows that prosecutors will offer a deal to criminals in exchange for testimony favouring their case.
Doesn't this give an unfair advantage to the prosecution over the defence?
Consider this scenario. A rich husband is found murdered in his home, prosecution think the wife did it. During the investigation it comes to light that the crime was witnessed by a burglar breaking into a house across the street.
The witness doesn't want to testify. His personal best option is to say nothing since any statement he give will provide evidence of his own crime.
If the witness says he saw the wife commit the murder then the prosecution might agree to overlook his burglary in exchange for his testimony.
If the witness says he saw someone else commit the crime, then the prosecution have no interest in his testimony and have no motivation to overlook his burglary. The defense on the other hand will want him to testify, but can't offer him any deal - the best option for the burglar would be to refuse to testify, or if forced to testify then to deny being present.
Have I understood the law correctly? Or can the defence also offer a deal in exchange for testimony? (Or is it possible that American cop shows don't stick to the truth?)
UPDATE - similar questions involving witness immunity all talk about the prosecution being able to offer immunity for statements that will help the prosecution only. What about statements that will help the defence only?

Why wouldn't the prosecution want the witness if it points to the true criminal being aprehended? A different issue would be the prosecution dismissing the witness as unreliable; and that could be in part because the evidence they have at the moment bias them against the husband. But it would not be, at least in theory, because the prosecution wants to condemn the husband no matter if he is guilty or not.

@SJuan76 - If all the witness can do is prevent the prosecution from convicting it's prime suspect (without actually suggesting who's really guilty) then the prosecution may prefer him not to appear?

So you are suposing that prosecution would charge someone they think is innocent? Just for the sake of it? Also, prosecutors might not be forced to offer immunity, but they have an obligation to disclose to the defense that such a witness exists.

@SJuan - I'm sure the prosecution wouldn't charge someone THEY think is innocent, but the defence might think they're innocent! The issue is that the prosecution have little cause to persuade an witness for the defence to testify

Why would the defense care if someone is innocent or not? Their job is to defend someone of the charges and if possible get them found not guilty regardless of if they think the person is innocent or not.

In most countries, the burden of proof is on the prosecution, not the defense. If the prosecution thinks someone is guilty - they have to prove it. Defense doesn't need to prove innocence, only show that the prosecution lacks the ability to prove their case beyond a reasonable doubt.

@littleadv: That is the theory, but in the actual courtroom, what happens is that the prosecution tells a story, then the defense tells a story, and the jury decides which story they believe. While the defense is notionally entitled to tell no story at all and simply poke holes in the prosecution's story, actually doing so in practice makes for a weak defense because the jury will struggle to envision a plausible alternative version of events, as is arguably required in many jurisdictions.

Yes, what I mean is that the prosecution's story has to be "this guy did it, and here's why", while the defense's doesn't have to be "no, he didn't". It may be "That guy did it", or "who said anyone did anything?", or "that's not a crime", or "he's mentally ill and is not responsible for his actions" etc.

@Kevin you've obviously never been on a jury. From experience as a juror in deep red Trump-land, I promise that it's easy to poke holes in a weak case.

@RonJohn: Who said anything about a weak prosecution? If the prosecution puts on a weak case in the first instance, then of course the defense has less of a need to put on a strong case in response. If the prosecution's case is especially weak, the defense may even prefer to put on a weak response, because it shows that they are refusing to take the prosecution's argument seriously. But in my comment, I was assuming we were talking about the usual scenario in which prosecutors prefer to bring strong cases rather than weak cases.

@Kevin "I was assuming".  Don't assume.  And don't assume that all prosecutors know that all their cases are weak, or that their rhetorical skills aren't strong enough to overcome what they know is a weak case, or that the defense attorney's rhetorical skills are better than the prosecutor's skills.

@RonJohn: Would you kindly refrain from instructing me on what political beliefs I should or should not hold?

@Kevin political beliefs???  Rereading my comments, I don't see where I "instruct(ed) (you) on what political beliefs (you) should or should not hold".

@RonJohn: Prosecutors are (at the state level, which is what you seem to be describing) elected officials. Their level of competence is a political matter.

@Kevin (1) District Attorneys are elected officials; the Assistant District Attorneys who go to court and prosecute 99.9% of cases are not elected. (2) What does that have to do with " instructing (you) on what political beliefs I should or should not hold"?

@RonJohn: If you can't see how "Don't assume [...]" falls into that category, then I am unable to help you understand.

@Kevin sure you can: it's called "explaining".

The question is weird. Since it is the prosecution (and not the defense) prosecuting (nomen est omen, isn't it), it is only the prosecution (and not the defense) who can abstain from prosecuting, as part of a deal. What am I missing?

Your case is also very untypical. A witness who might be offered a deal is typically part of the criminal operation or at least organization: That makes the typical witness a witness to the prosecution. A witness who would incriminate themselves for an unrelated crime and be a witness for the defense is a rare coincidence.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: A defendant accused of playing some role in a criminal scheme could seek aquittal by denying the existence of a criminal scheme, but also by showing that the tasks the defendant was accused of performing were likely done by someone else.  Another person involved in the scheme might be able to e.g. offer evidence that acts were performed at a time when it would have been impossible for the defendant to have performed them.

united-states
The defense cannot offer a plea deal to another potential criminal defendant, because (in all but a handful of U.S. states, and for all but a small number of offenses even in those states), private citizens can't charge people with crimes.
But, the defense can subpoena a witness to force that witness to testify (this is a constitutional right). And, the prosecution had a duty, called a Brady duty after the U.S. Supreme Court case creating the duty as a matter of federal constitutional law, to disclose exculpatory evidence in its possession (including witness statements) to the defense.
If the prosecution discloses information that the witness has, the defense can compel that witness to testify on the behalf of the defense.
Frequently, the defense can also compel the court to grant the witness use immunity for the compelled testimony if it would be self-incriminating, preventing the witness from claiming a 5th Amendment privilege when providing the subpoena compelled testimony.

canada
Yes; defence has no ability to offer a deal.
You also ask:

Doesn't this give an unfair advantage to the prosecution over the defence?

It is well known that that lessening the punishment a witness will face might be a motivation to lie. Such witnesses trigger the need for the judge to consider giving a Vetrovec warning (named after the case where the principle originated).
Such a warning is needed for certain "unsavoury or disreputable" witnesses when they provide inculpatory reference. Various factors go into deciding whether such a warning is required, including whether the witness received benefits for cooperation such that there is a risk he is lying to the court.


Did the witness have any motive to lie or mislead the court?

Did the witness receive benefits for cooperation such that there is a risk he is lying to the court?

Did the witness have a long criminal history?

Did the witness have a history of lying to or manipulating the police?

Was the witness an accomplice with knowledge of the circumstances such that it would be easy to falsely implicate the
accused?

Did the witness have access to disclosure or other information that may explain his evidence or how it was given?

Did the witness minimize his own wrongdoing?

Did the witness exhibit selective memory?

Did important evidence emerge only after the witness exhausted his memory or after prodding by police?

Did new information emerge for the first time at trial despite many previous statements?

Was the witness evasive?

Was the witness testimony inconsistent with external evidence, particularly objective evidence that has been accepted?

Did the witness provide prior inconsistent statements?

Was the witness internally consistent: did the witness evidence change in testifying?

Upon the application of common sense, is the witness evidence impossible, improbable or unlikely?



The warning should include:

(1) drawing the attention of the jury to the testimonial evidence requiring special scrutiny; (2) explaining why this evidence is subject to special scrutiny; (3) cautioning the jury that it is dangerous to convict on unconfirmed evidence of this sort, though the jury is entitled to do so if satisfied that the evidence is true; and (4) that the jury, in determining the veracity of the suspect evidence, should look for evidence from another source tending to show that the untrustworthy witness is telling the truth as to the guilt of the accused.


So are you saying that the "Vetrovec warning" abnegates the advantage to the prosecution of giving deals to witnesses? Or are you saying that, yes, this is an advantage that the prosecution has over the defense?
